# openvpn: client-connect script cannot write to /tmp file

Tags: openvpn

I have the following in my server.conf file...

```
client-connect /etc/openvpn/scripts/client-connect.bash
```

client-connect.bash so far looks like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

touch /tmp/testfile.txt

sleep 10

exit 0
```

I know that the script executes, because the client pauses for 10 seconds, and then successfully connects.

However the file /tmp/testfile.txt is never created.

I can't figure out what could be going wrong.

I was hoping to be able to write to /tmp, to allow me to echo environment variables etc. to help with finishing the actual script functionality. However without being able to write somewhere I have no way to see what's actually happening in the script.

Comment: sounds to me like you have wrong permissons on /tmp, even the openvpn user should be able to write there.

Comment: I've confirmed that the openvpn-user can write to /tmp. If I su to that account, and run the script directly, it works. It just doesn't work when it runs from the openvpn config. Anyway I realised that it may not be required, as I can get the output directly in the normal openvpn.log, which is all I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **PrivateTmp** directive in systemd openvpn unit's config.
Create /etc/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service.d/10-override.conf file with following content:

```
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
```

and you'll be able to write to /tmp in your scripts (if you really need to).

Change **openvpn-server@.service.d** to **openvpn-server@YOURCONF.service.d** to match only your config /etc/openvpn/server/YOURCONF.conf, or just **openvpn@.service.d** for old style /etc/openvpn/*.conf